# Remove here-doc syntax coloring on emacs

Tags: emacs

Hi is there a way to remove the here-doc syntax highlighting in emacs useing `cperl-mode`

It is highlighting the entire thing as a "String" which is technically correct but I do not want it to do that. When i program in `pico`/`nano` I make my own regular expressions to do syntax highlighting and it works great because it colors the here-docs like it colors the rest. It would be nice to learn how to create or where to insert my existing syntax highlighting regex's.

For example

```
print <<EOF;
This is not colored but "this is colored liek a string"
EOF
```

In emacs the entire thing is colored like a string which I dislike. How can i either turn here-doc syntax coloring off or edit the regular expressions directly like i do with `pico`?

Comment: Say what "here-doc" syntax coloring is and what causes it. It is not part of the default Emacs behavior from `emacs -Q`. After you specify this, I think the answer will be more or less obvious. IOW, it sounds like you are shooting yourself in the foot. If so, the answer will be "*Don't do that*". It sounds like it is you, or something you load, that turns on "here-doc".

Comment: @Drew, it is likely that the OP is referring to a feature built into `shell-script-mode`, or possibly `perl-mode` or `cperl-mode`. [Heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) are, essentially, multi-line strings in many shells and in Perl.

Comment: @Chris: this or this or this is likely... The OP would help the OP if the OP would specify what is involved. ;-)

Comment: Sorry if my question wasnt clear. I want to remove here-doc syntax highlighting i use `cperl-mode`. In `perl-mode` the problem is not there but i dislike it for other reasons.

BTW i have no idea why you bring up shooting myself in the foot.. the point of emacs is to be customizable and i enjoy writing regular expressions. I have always and will always write my own custom syntax highlighting regex. How do i do this with emacs? that would allow me to make the needed edits. And i enjoy doing this so its not shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Im not sure how to rephrase my question =(